# In set theory, is a bar above a letter the same as the tilda?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is an A with a horizontal line above it the same as an A with a tilda before it? eg: ~A

So, are they both the complement (opposite) of A?

Comment: That depends on author's notation, which should be defined somewhere in text. But I've seen both notations for complement in different books.

Comment: Remark: the symbol ~ is called a **tilde** with an e on the end.

Answer (score 1):

$\overline A$ is the complement of the set A.
~A is the negation of the statement A.
No, they are not the same.
One is a set, the other a statement.
The usual notation for the complement of A is A$^c$.

Comment: I have seen the tilde used for complement of a set, though usually placed over the set letter.